# How to interpret Tensorflow Histograms and Distribution plots

Tags: tensorflow, histogram, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am implementing a two-layer RNN. When I run the code, I have the following plots for weights and biases for the two layers of RNN.

(Sorry not enough reputation to include images on SO, please click on links.)

[Plot for RNN cell 0](https://s31.postimg.cc/yoh8ynud7/lstm_cell_0_kernel.png)

[Plot for RNN cell 1](https://s31.postimg.cc/e4cf0bc2z/lstm_cell_1_kernel.png)

By looking at these plots, I don't understand if the network is getting trained or not.

Can you please help me interpret these plots? General links to understanding TF histograms and distribution plots will also be appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can see that the distribution of the weignts in your graph changes (not much overall, though maybe some weights do change a lot), so you know for sure that *some training is happening*. What would really tell you if you're training correctly is the plot of the loss function, and if possible some other evaluation metrics (precision / accuracy for instance) over time, which you can get with

```
tf.summary.scalar('loss', your_loss_tensor)
all_summaries = tf.summary.merge_all()  # Op that needs to be run in the sess.run() call.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The loss starts decreasing from around 1.8 but then oscillates between a range (eg. 0.01 to 0.1). Could you comment on the distribution of the weights? I expected the variance of the Gaussian distribution in the plot to be much larger. Instead the weights seem to concentrate together, leading me to believe that a lot of the weights have same values. Could this indicate some problem with the training process?